# Custom Wordpress Query not showing 2nd page Pagination results

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm believe I'm having some scoping issues trying to get this code to work and I'm not exactly sure where. I have an index page where I have a container that allows me to filter my blog posts.[image: Front-end]

When I create my query to sort the type of posts by categories the pagination WILL create the right about of pages it needs, but it will not display any results on any page after the first page and will instead display the "No content found" from my code. I've looked into loads of potential solutions and the Wordpress documentation for pagination and paginate_links(), with all of them giving the same solution for displaying pagination for custom WP_Query's. I think I might be having a scoping issue due to the way I specifically have my code laid out to display the posts compared to all the examples I've seen.

**My Query Code**

```
// Display all posts initially
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$allPosts = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  "post_type" => 'post',
  'paged' => $paged,
  "cat" => 0
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($allPosts);

// Grab all categories from DB to display in form
$allCategories = get_categories();

foreach ($allCategories as $category) {
  $filterCategories[] = $category->name;
}
  
function returnFilteredCategories() {
  if (array_key_exists('filteredCategories', $_GET)) {
    foreach ($_GET['filteredCategories'] as $category ) {
      $categoriesArray[] = get_cat_ID($category);
    }
    $categoriesString = implode(",", $categoriesArray);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($categoriesString);
    echo '</pre>';
  } else {
    $categoriesString = 0;
  }

  if (get_query_var( 'paged' )) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
  } elseif(get_query_var('page')) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'page');
  } else {
    $paged = 1;
  }
  $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
      "cat" => $categoriesString,
      'paged' => $paged,
  );
  $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

  return $the_query;
}

if (isset($_GET['category-filter'])) {
  $the_query = returnFilteredCategories();
}
```

**My Loop**

```
<div class="archive__template-data flex justify-evenly">
    
    <div class="archive__filter-fields pt-150px px-100px w-max">
      <h6 class="text-frm-navy">Filters</h6>
      <div class="border-1 border-gray my-20px"></div>
      <form action="" class="filter__form flex flex-col w-max pr-70px">
      <?php foreach ($filterCategories as $category) { ?>
        <label for="<?php echo $category; ?>" class="block relative cursor-pointer pl-40px hover:bg-gray mb-4">
          <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            id="<?php echo $category; ?>" 
            name="filteredCategories[]" 
            value="<?php echo $category; ?>"
            class="absolute opacity-0 cursor-pointer w-0 h-0"
          >
          <span class="filtered-categories__checkmark absolute top-0 left-0 h-4 w-4 bg-white rounded border-1 border-frm-olive after:content-checkmark box-content after:absolute after:hidden checked:after:block"></span>
        <?php echo $category ?></label>
      <?php } ?>
      <input type="submit" value="filter" class="primary-button primary-button-navy w-24 flex justify-center cursor-pointer" name="category-filter">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="max-w-800px pt-150px px-140px bg-white box-content">
      <?php 
      if ($the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          $the_query->the_post();
          $postID = get_the_ID();
          $date = get_the_time('d - M - Y', $postID);
          $title = get_the_title($postID);
          $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($postID);
          $permalink = get_the_permalink($postID);
          $categories = get_the_category($postID);
            ?>
            <div class="flex text-frm-green font-bold mb-9 mt-16">
              <?php 
              foreach( $categories as $category ) { 
                echo'<h6 class="mr-10px">';
                echo $category->name;
                echo'</h6>';
              } 
              ?>
            </div>
            <div class="uppercase text-excerpt text-gray mb-25px"><?php echo $date; ?></div>
            <h3 class="text-frm-navy font-extrabold mb-25px"><a href="<?php echo $permalink ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></h3>
            <div class="mb-7"><?php echo $excerpt; ?></div>
            <a class="underline uppercase arrow-link alternate text-frm-dark-blue hover:text-frm-blue" href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>">get the details<span class="right-arrow"></span></a>
            <div class="border-b-2 border-gray mt-16"></div> 
            <?php
          ?>
          <?php get_template_part( 'parts/partials', get_post_format() );
        }
        ?>
        <div class="pagination-nav flex">
          <div><?php
            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
 
            echo paginate_links( array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
            ) )
          ?></div>
        </div>
        
        <?php
        } else {
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
      ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

any help would greatly be appreciated. I feel like it's something simple that I'm missing and I just can't see it.

Comment: Sometimes it is easiest to just look at the [literal SQL query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/110269) that was generated. I’m also a little confused because you have code in a function, and code before and after it, and they share a lot of variable names which can add to confusion.

Comment: I have been going back and forth between trying multiple approaches to this, sorry for the messy code. My thought process was i would define `$the_query` initially with every post, then the function would re-set that variable with the current categories that were selected in my form, that way I could keep using the same variable for my loop

Comment: Although not right or wrong, I think I’d recommend making a similar function called `getAllCategories` so that you don’t pollute the variable space and potentially confuse things. I also strongly push people to [`get_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755) because it also doesn’t have side effects, but it does mean you have to occasionally setup the loop manually.

Comment: So I actually originally had it set up with `get_posts` which I thought was a lot cleaner and how i typically do this sort of thing, but I was having issues getting the pagination working, and any examples/documentation I could find used a `WP_Query` loop. I really appreciate the information in that link! Down below I noticed someone also says **"For this reason, get_posts() should be used for non paginated queries only. Paginating get_posts is really one big mess. WP_Query should be used for all paginated queries"**.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed the pagination. Yep, in that case, it is probably much, much easier to use `WP_Query`, I totally agree with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally after about two weeks of messing with this I figured out that my issue was mostly the form I was using to make the query. I've cleaned up my code a bit as well which helped out a ton as far as trying to read what was going on.

**this is what the query logic looks like now**

```
// check to see if there have been any filtered categories
if (isset($_GET['filteredCategories'])) {
    foreach ($_GET['filteredCategories'] as $category) {
      $categoriesArray[] = get_cat_ID($category);
    }
    $categoriesString = implode(",", $categoriesArray);
} else {
  // if not, grab all categories
  $categoriesString = 0;
}

// get the 'paged' global query variable for the current page in pagination
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

// create the query
$queryArgs = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
      "post_type" => 'post',
      'paged' => $paged,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      "cat" => $categoriesString
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($queryArgs);
```

**My loop stayed the same.**

**This is what was the issue (My old Form)**

```
  <form method="" action="/my-index-page/">
  <?php foreach ($filterCategories as $category) { ?>
    <label for="<?php echo $category; ?>" c">
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        id="<?php echo $category; ?>" 
        name="filteredCategories[]" 
        value="<?php echo $category; ?>"
      >
    <?php echo $category ?></label>
  <?php } ?>
  <input type="submit" name="category-filter" value="filtered">. //I had added a name and value attribute for the submit here
  </form>
```

**Here I removed the name and value from the submit input**

```
<form method="" action="/my-index-page/">
  <?php foreach ($filterCategories as $category) { ?>
    <label for="<?php echo $category; ?>" c">
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        id="<?php echo $category; ?>" 
        name="filteredCategories[]" 
        value="<?php echo $category; ?>"
      >
    <?php echo $category ?></label>
  <?php } ?>
  <input type="submit"> //removed name and value attributes here
  </form>
```

I'm not exactly sure why I added that originally but it was screwing with the pagination and was removing one of my filtered categories every time I clicked to go to the next page. So if I clicked 2 categories I wanted to filter by, the next page would have removed one of them and then displayed 0 results.